# "I invite you for / to coffee" is correct?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

If I'm inviting a person to drink coffe with me, then can I say "I invite you **for** / to **coffe**" or should I add a noun or a verb such as "I invite you for **drinking** coffee" / "I invite you to **drink** coffee"?

Comment: I invite you for coffee

Comment: An invitation should be to an event or activity, not an object. Maybe "I would like to invite you to have coffee with me."

Comment: In typical speech, people usually leave out the word "invite" when inviting someone.  If you are inviting them to join you in getting coffee somewhere, you could say, "Would you like to join me for coffee?" or "Let's get some coffee."  If it is for a later date, you could say, "Let's get together for coffee."  If you are inviting them to your house for coffee, you could say, "Would you like to come over for coffee?"  Or for a later date, "You should come over for coffee sometime." or "It would be great to have you over for coffee."

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invite+you+to+coffee%2C+invite+you+for+coffee&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvite%20you%20to%20coffee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvite%20you%20for%20coffee%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invite) defines **invite** as **to ask or request someone to go to an event**

You might invite somebody to a party, you might invite several people to a "coffee morning"- an organized event, often to raise money for charity- but you wouldn't normally invite one person for coffee.  For events, the preposition **to** is always used.

In addition, you wouldn't normally use the word invite directly to the person: "I invite you"- either verbally or in writing. You use it to talk about people that you want to, or have, invited

> This is a list of the people that I have invited so far...

or to tell somebody that you have been invited by somebody.

> I was invited to their wedding but I wasn't free

In a formal, written invitation, you (the inviter) would talk about yourself in the third person:

> John and June invite you to the marriage of...

Or use passive voice:

> You are cordially invited to the marriage of...

More suitable ways of making a verbal invitation would be:

> Would you like to join me for coffee? - *formal*
>   Let's go grab a coffee - *informal*

You can use the same invitations for lunch, a beer... whatever.

Note that some non-native English speakers (particularly Russians) use the word **invite** incorrectly:  when they say "I invite you for coffee", they mean "I would like to have coffee with you **and I will pay**". For native English speakers, an invitation doesn't necessarily mean that the inviter will pay.

If you do want to offer to pay, there are many options, including these:

> Would you allow me to buy you a coffee? - *very formal*
>   Let me buy you a coffee - *informal*
>   Let's go for a coffee- it's on me - *informal*
>   Let's go for a coffee- it's my shout - *very informal*

Comment: Regarding to your end of the answer, how could you can imply that you're going to pay? I know some language which use the verb "invite" for it, and I assumed that's the same in English.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent, to indicate covering the payment, we typically use the word "treat", meaning to pay another's expenses.  So we would tack on a phrase after the invitation like, "my treat" or "I'll treat".  An alternative phrase would be "on me" or "it's on me", meaning I'll pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

I invite you for coffee.

I invite you to coffee.

Both are grammatical. I think there's no hard and fast rule as to which preposition we should prefer when we are talking about something to eat or drink.  In this case, the former sounds more common and idiomatic. Strangely enough, if you are talking about tea, lunch or dinner, people usually  use the preposition "to", for example:

I invite you to tea/lunch/dinner.

As for the second part of the OP's question, you don't usually use the preposition "for" with the -ing form of a verb to convey your purpose or intention. Instead, you  use a to-infinitive.  So you say:

I invite you to drink coffee.

Further, you can use the for + -ing form to express the pupose or function of something, for example:

This knife is for slicing  bread.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invite+you+to+tea%2C+invite+you+for+tea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvite%20you%20to%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvite%20you%20for%20tea%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There's a machine for slicing bread? What happened to **sliced bread**? :) There's a kind of bread knife for slicing bread...

Comment: @Mari-LouA,  A machine for slicing bread (Oxford Learner's Dictionary.  Anyway, thanks for your comments .  I have edited my answer replacing machine  with knife

Answer (score 2):

### How to ask someone to meet for a coffee

- *You are **invited to** coffee tomorrow morning at 10.00*
  A very formal construction (simple present passive), totally inappropriate for a casual invitation, no one *says* this to any friend, or even, acquaintance.
- *Can I **invite** you **for** a coffee?*
  I feel using *invite you **to***, suggests that the coffee will be limited to one cup. A bit standoffish if you ask me.
- **Would you like** to go out **for** a coffee?
  A good balance between politeness and friendliness without sounding cold or overly formal.
- ***Shall*** we have a coffee?
  Polite, friendly and non-committal.
- ***How about*** a coffee one of these days?
- *Let's **get**/ **grab** a coffee.*
- *Let's **meet for** coffee*
- *Do you **fancy** (a) coffee?*
  British English, very colloquial, friendly and informal

Online I found an [article](http://www.englishandculture.com/blog/3-ways-to-casually-invite-someone-out-for-coffee-in-english) on three more ways to invite someone for a coffee. Note, two constructions use the preposition  *for*, but they all omit the verb *invite*

> - Would you like to grab a coffee next week?
> - Are you free for a coffee sometime in the next few days?
> - Are you up for a coffee this weekend?

Comment: How "invite you **to**" feels to you as limited for one cup? I would really like to understand it. (For example if I'm talking friend-1 and telling him that I invited *to* coffee my friend-2, he should understand that I invited friend-2 for one cup only?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, when you use the term "invite someone for coffee," it doesn't mean literally that you will drink coffee and they will drink coffee.  It is actually fine  to order tea or ginger ale or something else non-alcoholic if you go to a restaurant or fast food place, etc. together.

Also, if you "go out for coffee" with someone, it's fine to order a snack as well as the drink - a donut, muffin, piece of cake, or piece of pie are appropriate.  (I realize this sounds silly to be so precise, but I was born in the USA, and these are the rules, more or less!). Do not order something more substantial than a snack such as a salad or an entree, because "going out for coffee" implies that the socializing might be very brief, like only 10 minutes.  Although sometimes "coffee" can last as long as an hour or 2, if both people want to talk a long time.

If you are so hungry that you want something more than a drink and a snack, you should do some polite ritualized social apologizing and negotiating before you accept someone's invitation.  Say something like, "Oh, coffee sounds great.  But I didn't have breakfast this morning and I'm really hungry.  Are you by any chance up for doing lunch in an hour instead?"

Also, if you invite someone to "go out for coffee" with you, it is understood to mean that you will not sit silently as you drink coffee.  It actually means that you are making a friendly outreach and want to socialize (chat) with the person.  The chat could be about a casual topic, or if it feels appropriate, the conversation could become serious.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! While this may be correct, it doesn't really help clear the confusion, which is about which preposition to use. Please have a moment to read the [tour] and the Help Center article [answer]; we're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.