# preposition before coffee

Tags: prepositions

Should I say **by** coffee, **at** coffee or **on** coffee? What preposition should we use before coffee, lunch, tea, dinner? Example:

> Let's meet up by coffee.

meaning I want to meet up with you at a cafe and drink coffee together.

Comment: Many people would not consider a preposition before they have had some coffee.  A good question.

Comment: Nearly identical [“I invite you for / to coffee” is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126872/i-invite-you-for-to-coffee-is-correct?rq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"By" gives method  (travel by train), it can also be used to give location (by the statue)

"at" and "on" give location or time. (let's meet at 5:00, on Oxford street)

You want to give purpose, and the preposition that gives purpose is "for"

> Let's meet for coffee.

(Drinking) coffee is the purpose of our meeting

Comment: Wow, what if the purpose of meeting is not only coffee, but the main purpose is e.g. discussing a project? Does _Let's meet for coffee and discuss the project._ express what I have in mind?

Comment: That is perfect.

Comment: I would add that if the purpose of your meeting is described only with a verb phrase, e.g. "discuss the project", then the words to use are "to" or "and": "Let's meet (at the cafe) to discuss the project" "Let's meet (at the cafe) and discuss the project"

Comment: @Elininja there are subtle differences between those statements that affect their meaning: "Let's meet for coffee _to_ discuss the project" implies that the purpose of the meeting is discussion of the project, while "Let's meet for coffee _and_ discuss the project" implies "meeting for coffee" and "discussing the project" are activities that coincide, but are not causally connected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that kind of nuance can be tricky even for native speakers.